# Explaination for the variable b to have value -116

Tags: c, oop

So I came across this snippet and after reading a bit about char and int calculations, I understand the gist that calculations are conducted in Int and here it's being printed as one. What I do not understand is how the variable b assumes the value -116 internally. Can anyone explain the math?
Note: this is in the domain of signed char only -128 to 127

```
int main()
    {
    char a=120,b=140;
    int i;
    i=a+b;
    printf("%d",i);
    }
```

ans=4, as a=120 and b=-116 in the compiler.

Comment: It would appear `char` is signed by default on your compiler and 8-bits long, and two's complement is used. This means that the bit pattern for `140` has the numeric value `-116`.

Comment: You already mentioned it: "signed char only -128 to 127". The calculation is only done in another instruction later. When `b` is initialized, the value needs to fit into `char`, not `int`

Comment: 116 is 2 complement of 140, as 116+140=256 what is 2^8,  a numberr of bits in char. Two complement is universal encoding of negative numbers used on all modern machines

Comment: Oh I see now, I wasn't able to find this logic of 2's complement, thanks guys, I will go study that up for more clarity.

Comment: You are converting a value of type `int` into `char`, while this value cannot be represented in `char`. So by C standard if `char` is signed, the result is implementation defined. In this case as commented above the implementation chosen to use 2's complement interpretation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `b` can't store `140` (because it is signed) the compiler will transform the value (in an implementation defined way) to something else that will fit in the range of a signed `char`.

In your case it turns out it uses the raw bits and just copies them into `b`, which for a `signed char` will mean `b` equals `-116` (in [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)).

So `a + b` will be equal to `120 + -116` which is `4`.

---

Also useful to know is that when you use values of smaller types than `int` in an arithmetic expression (as in `a + b` in your code) then the values undergoes [*usual arithmetic conversions*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions) which leads to them being [*promoted* to `int`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions).

The promotion to `int` will keep the sign (it does *sign extension*). So the `signed char` value `-116` becomes the `signed int` value `-116`.

Answer (score 0):

140 = 0x8C, which is a negative value if interpreted as a signed value, as the highest bit is set. Thus it will be printed as -116 in decimal notation.